# How to use a Java for loop in an html page

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my system i need to use a java for loop inside an html table to print time from 8.00-17.00. Can someone please explain me how to do it.Thank you.

Html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/timeTable.css" th:href="@{/css/timeTable.css}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Time Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
    <br><br>
    <table border="1" class="table2">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <br>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr>
            <% for(int i=0;i<17;i++){
            <td> i.":00 - ".($i+1).":00" </td>
        }
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That would have to be a JSP file (although javascript would work too). Also you are missing the closing `%>`

Comment: how to add a jsp file? Thank you

Comment: looks like you are using thymeleaf. So with thymeleaf you can iterate with `th:each` and no need for jsp file.

Comment: yes i'm using thymeleaf. how can i make a similar iteration to this using th:each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by using the following way. Thx everyone who tried to help

```
<option th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence( 8, 17)}">
     <tr>
         <th th:text="${ i }+':00 - ' + ${ i+1 }+':00'"></th>
     </tr>
 </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install JSTL as follows:

<`%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`
and then iterate over the list as follows:

```
<c:forEach var = "i" begin = "8.00" end = "17.00">
         Item <c:out value = "${i}"/><p>
      </c:forEach>
```

Comment: .jsp file only.

Comment: Or you can use javascript and render it on html page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Javascript instead of going nut with inventing stuff like that?
Javascript is a powerfull language and have a for loop as well.
let to the front which belongs to the front.